# Appache camel Gzip compression

Tags: amazon-s3, apache-camel, zip, compression, gzip

I'm trying to compress my file with gzip (to have .zip extension) but after compression i lost the original extension of my file into the archieve

.setHeader(Exchange.FILE_NAME,simple("RANSXY_VALD.dat"))

.marshal().gzipDeflater().to(toCtuUri + "&fileName=${file:name.noext}.zip")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get Zip compression, you have to use zipFile() instead of gzipDeflater()